ExpandoObject Datagrid rendering performance issue
I have a performance issue when trying to bind an ExpandoObject into my Datagrid: it takes far too long to load. For example, for 6 columns and 50 rows, it takes like 10 seconds!
I'm using ExpandoObject because I need to add a property to my object at runtime.
Basically, the user selects a "Test", then in my code I add two new columns named "X" and "Y" to my Datagrid. So for every test that the user checks, my code adds two more columns of "X and "Y".
Here's my code:
public void Fill_Table_Performance()
    {
        if (main.tab_table.IsSelected && main.Table_performance_AVG != null)
        {
            list_dynamic_object = new List<List<IDictionary<string, object>>>
            {
                new List<IDictionary<string, object>>(),new List<IDictionary<string, object>>(),
                new List<IDictionary<string, object>>(),new List<IDictionary<string, object>>()
            };

            List<double> list_count_oos = new List<double>
            {
                new double(),new double(),new double(),new double()
            };

            int count = -1;

            var List_Test_Num = main.Table_performance_AVG.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r => new { Test_Num = r["Test_Num"] })
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < List_Table_Performance.Count; i++)
            {
                count++;
                var list_column = List_Table_Performance[i].Columns.Where(x => x.Header.ToString().Contains("X") || x.Header.ToString().Contains("Y")).ToList();

                foreach (DataGridTextColumn column in list_column)
                {
                    List_Table_Performance[i].Columns.Remove(column);
                }

                List_Table_Performance[i].ItemsSource = null;

                foreach (DataRow Test_Num in List_Test_Num)
                {
                    var list_column_per_test = List_Table_Performance[i].Columns.Where(x => x.SortMemberPath.ToString() == "X" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString())).ToList();

                    if (list_column_per_test.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Binding Binding_X = new Binding();
                        Binding_X.Path = new PropertyPath("X" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString()));
                        Binding_X.IsAsync = true;

                        Binding Binding_Y = new Binding();
                        Binding_Y.Path = new PropertyPath("Y" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString()));
                        Binding_Y.IsAsync = true;

                        DataGridTextColumn Column_X = new DataGridTextColumn
                        {
                            Header = "X",
                            Binding = Binding_X,
                            Width = 50,
                            SortMemberPath = "X" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString())
                        };

                        Style columnStyle_X = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
                        DataTrigger Trigger_X = new DataTrigger();
                        Trigger_X.Binding = new Binding("Spec_X" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString()));
                        Trigger_X.Value = true;
                        Trigger_X.Setters.Add(
                            new Setter(
                                TextBlock.ForegroundProperty,
                                new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Firebrick)));
                        columnStyle_X.Triggers.Add(Trigger_X);
                        Column_X.ElementStyle = columnStyle_X;

                        DataGridTextColumn Column_Y = new DataGridTextColumn
                        {
                            Header = "Y",
                            Binding = Binding_Y,
                            Width = 50,
                            SortMemberPath = "Y" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString())
                        };

                        Style columnStyle_Y = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
                        DataTrigger Trigger_Y = new DataTrigger();
                        Trigger_Y.Binding = new Binding("Spec_Y" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString()));
                        Trigger_Y.Value = true;
                        Trigger_Y.Setters.Add(
                            new Setter(
                                TextBlock.ForegroundProperty,
                                new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Firebrick)));
                        columnStyle_Y.Triggers.Add(Trigger_Y);
                        Column_Y.ElementStyle = columnStyle_Y;

                        List_Table_Performance[i].Columns.Add(Column_X);
                        List_Table_Performance[i].Columns.Add(Column_Y);
                    }
                }

                foreach (DataRow dt in main.Table_performance_AVG.Rows)
                {
                    List<dynamic> list_date = list_dynamic_object[i].Cast<dynamic>().Where(x => x.Date == ((DateTime)dt["Date"]).ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss").ToString()).ToList();
                    List<dynamic> list_recipe = list_dynamic_object[i].Cast<dynamic>().Where(x => x.Recipe == dt["Recipe_Name"].ToString()).ToList();

                    if (list_date.Count() == 0 || dt["Test_Num"].ToString() == list_date[0].Test_Num)
                    {
                        IDictionary<string, object> table = new ExpandoObject();

                        table.Add("Recipe", list_recipe.Any() == false ? dt["Recipe_Name"].ToString() : "");
                        table.Add("Date", ((DateTime)dt["Date"]).ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss").ToString());
                        table.Add("X" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString(), dt[i + count].ToString() == "-99999" ? null : (double?)dt[i + count]);
                        table.Add("Y" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString(), dt[i + 1 + count].ToString() == "-99999" ? null : (double?)dt[i + 1 + count]);
                        table.Add("Spec_X" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString(), false);
                        table.Add("Spec_Y" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString(), false);
                        table.Add("Test_Num", dt["Test_Num"].ToString());

                        if (i > 0)
                        {
                            if (dt[List_Table_Performance[i].Uid + "_Spec"].ToString() != "-99999")
                            {
                                if (List_Table_Performance[i].Uid == "Test" ?
                                (double.Parse(table["X" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()].ToString()) > double.Parse(dt[List_Table_Performance[i].Uid + "_Spec"].ToString()) ||
                                double.Parse(table["X" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()].ToString()) < double.Parse(dt[List_Table_Performance[i].Uid + "_Spec"].ToString()) * -1) :
                                (double.Parse(table["X" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()].ToString()) > double.Parse(dt[List_Table_Performance[i].Uid + "_Spec"].ToString())
                                || double.Parse(table["X" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()].ToString()) < 0))
                                {
                                    table["Spec_X" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()] = true;
                                }

                                if (List_Table_Performance[i].Uid == "Test" ?
                                    (double.Parse(table["Y" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()].ToString()) > double.Parse(dt[List_Table_Performance[i].Uid + "_Spec"].ToString()) ||
                                    double.Parse(table["Y" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()].ToString()) < double.Parse(dt[List_Table_Performance[i].Uid + "_Spec"].ToString()) * -1) :
                                    (double.Parse(table["Y" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()].ToString()) > double.Parse(dt[List_Table_Performance[i].Uid + "_Spec"].ToString())
                                    || double.Parse(table["Y" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()].ToString()) < 0))
                                {
                                    table["Spec_Y" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()] = true;
                                }

                                if (bool.Parse(table["Spec_X" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()].ToString()) == true || bool.Parse(table["Spec_Y" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()].ToString()) == true)
                                {
                                    list_count_oos[i]++;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        list_dynamic_object[i].Add(table);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                            int index = list_dynamic_object[i].Cast<dynamic>().ToList().IndexOf(list_date[0]);

                            IDictionary<string, object> table_new_test = list_date[0] as IDictionary<string, object>;
                            table_new_test.Add("X" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString(), dt[i + count].ToString() == "-99999" ? null : (double?)dt[i + count]);
                            table_new_test.Add("Y" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString(), dt[i + 1 + count].ToString() == "-99999" ? null : (double?)dt[i + 1 + count]);
                            //table_ovl1.X1 = main.Table_performance_AVG.Rows[main.Table_performance_AVG.Rows.Count - 1][i].ToString() == "-99999.0" ? null : main.Table_performance_AVG.Rows[main.Table_performance_AVG.Rows.Count - 1][i].ToString();
                            //table_ovl1.Y1 = main.Table_performance_AVG.Rows[main.Table_performance_AVG.Rows.Count - 1][i].ToString() == "-99999.0" ? null : main.Table_performance_AVG.Rows[main.Table_performance_AVG.Rows.Count - 1][i].ToString();
                            table_new_test["Test_Num"] = dt["Test_Num"].ToString();

                            list_dynamic_object[i][index] = table_new_test;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < List_Table_Performance.Count; i++)
            {
                List_Table_Performance[i].ItemsSource = list_dynamic_object[i];
                List_Table_Performance_OOS[i].Text = "Out of Spec: " + Math.Ceiling((list_count_oos[i] / (List_Table_Performance[i].Items.Count)) * 100) + "%";
            }
        }
    }

I set some property of the Datagrid like AutoGenerateColumns="False" and ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"; it helps for the scrolling but not for the rendering.

Just seems like a lot of code for the case where a user can't decide how many columns thet want, beforehand. Also, the "async" code says "I'm not in a hurry". ExpandoObject also implies "interpreting"; not compiling.

I put all the function to be clearer.
The user can't know before how many columns he needs. He can select 2 tests or 50.
the async code is one of the things i did to improve the DataGrid rendering according to some post i saw here.

Why not datatable? Bind the defaultview.

I thought about the DataTable also, i will try Thank you!

Found the solution
You need to fill a Dynamic DataTable, and Bind the defaultview to the DataGrid.
DataTable Table_Performance_Data = new DataTable();

Table_Performance_Data.Columns.Add("Recipe");
Table_Performance_Data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime)));

Create Column in DataGrid:
Binding Binding_X = new Binding();
Binding_X.Path = new PropertyPath("X" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString()));

Binding Binding_Y = new Binding();
Binding_Y.Path = new PropertyPath("Y" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString()));

DataGridTextColumn Column_X = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
       Header = "X",
       Binding = Binding_X,
       Width = 50,
       SortMemberPath = "X" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString())
    };

DataGridTextColumn Column_Y = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
       Header = "Y",
       Binding = Binding_Y,
       Width = 50,
       SortMemberPath = "Y" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString())
    };

Add the column to the DataTable
Table_Performance_Data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("X" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString()), typeof(double)) { AllowDBNull = true });
Table_Performance_Data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Y" + int.Parse(Test_Num["Test_Num"].ToString()), typeof(double)) { AllowDBNull = true });

Fill the DataTable
foreach (DataRow dt in main.Table_performance_AVG.Rows)
{
   DataRow row = List_Table_Performance_Data[i].NewRow();

   row["Recipe"] = list_recipe.Any() == false ? dt["Recipe_Name"].ToString() : "";
   row["Date"] = ((DateTime)dt["Date"]).ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss").ToString();
   row["X" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()] = dt[i + count].ToString() == "-99999" ? null : (double?)dt[i + count];
   row["Y" + dt["Test_Num"].ToString()] = dt[i + 1 + count].ToString() == "-99999" ? null : (double?)dt[i + 1 + count];

   Table_Performance_Data.Rows.Add(row);
}

Bind the DataTable to the DataGrid
DataGrid.ItemsSource = Table_Performance_Data.DefaultView;

